# JavaScript Error: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, typeerror

I have a simple example:
`util.js` and `app.js` are in the same directory.

In `util.js`

```
export function existy(x)
{
   return x !== null && x != undefined;
}
```

In `app.js`

```
import {existy} from 'util';

var x = undefined;
if (!existy(x))
{
    console.log('x doesn't exist');
}
```

But I got a TypeError: Object(...) is not a function on the line I use `existy` function in `app.js`. What makes it think existy is not a function?

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you importing `existy ` from the right folder? Can you do absolute import of that folder?

Comment: Have you checked that you are correctly importing the function given your build/folder set-up? I've tried it inline and it works fine.

Comment: you most likely want to change your import of util.js to a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should import like this:

```
import {existy} from './util';
```

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you! The error message is really misleading. If it is an import error, I would expect some kind of "Not Found" instead of "Not a function" error.

Comment: Not a function is thrown when the function imported is not a properly defined function or else the function is never defined.